# Oracle SQL statement dynamic schema variable

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have some hundred lines of code to create tables but schema name is hardcoded like SCHEMA_NAME1.TABLE_NAME in all DDL statements. How can I have this as a variable  and use in all the places so that we can easily change in a single place for multiple locations of SCHEMA_NAME requirement.Please give your thoughts.

```
create table SCHEMA_NAME1.TABLE_NAME1(....);
create table SCHEMA_NAME1.TABLE_NAME2(....);
create table SCHEMA_NAME1.TABLE_NAME3(....);
```

I want something like this

```
var SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE ;
create table SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE.TABLE_NAME1(....);
create table SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE.TABLE_NAME2(....);
create table SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE.TABLE_NAME3(....);
```

Comment: You will have to write a PL/SQL program to get to that and use dynamic sql. Can't you just use a text editor and replace the instances before creating DDL scripts for different environments?

Comment: If you can use SQL*Plus then use substitution variables - `create table &SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME1(....);` and execute the script with schema parameter. If the code creates only tables, view or grants you can turn everything into single `CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION` command.

Comment: Using only a single ampersand `&` for each instance of the schema name would require the user to enter the schema name once for each instance of the substitution variable.  Using either a double ampersand `&&` for the first occurrence, or an [`ACCEPT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1006991) command at the beginning of the script would allow for entering the value only once.  The `ACCEPT` command is the more advisable method since it ensures you can set the value each time you run the script.  You should also include an `UNDEFINE` at the end.

Comment: When using substitution (`&`) variables, don't forget to double up the trailing period since a period is used as an optional termination character for the variable names. The period termination character is required when the variable is name is not followed by white space as is the case above, so you need to double it in order to not lose the period separating the schema name from the object name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SQL*Plus or SQLcl to run your object creation script, use substitution (`&`) variables in place of the hard coded schema names, with a leading [`ACCEPT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1006991) command and a trailing [`UNDEFINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1014278) command.  When the variable has no trailing white space, terminate the variable name with a period (`.`).

```
ACCEPT SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE
create table &SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE..TABLE_NAME1(....);
create table &SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE..TABLE_NAME2(....);
create table &SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE..TABLE_NAME3(....);
UNDEFINE SCHEMA_NAME_VALUE
```

Comment: But normally without anytools its not useful.

Comment: @sunleo if you don't have any tools how do you plan to run it in the first place?

Comment: This can be done like batch job from java, so I don't think we need some tools in that case.