# Dynamic parameter name on PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I was trying to generate a multiplication algorithm for multiple parameters using dynamic PL/SQL. I agree there are multiple approaches out there for doing this but this multiplication problem is a PoC for something else that I need to do.

So here is the code

```
declare
  var1    number := 1;
  var2    number := 2;
  output  number := 1;
  varname varchar2(10);
begin
  for counter in 1..2
  loop
    execute immediate q'[select var]'||counter||' * :val1 from dual' into output using output;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(output);
end;
```

So what I was trying to do is generate the parameter name at run time and then evaluate that parameter name.

Is this feasible? Deep down I don't think so... but kind of hoping to avoid the huge pain coming my way if this does not work. :). BTW I am on Oracle 11GR2.

Here is what happened when I ran the code.

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
declare
  var1    number := 1;
  var2    number := 2;
  output  number := 1;
  varname varchar2(10);
begin
  for counter in 1..2
  loop
    execute immediate q'[select var]'||counter||' * :val1 from dual' into output using output;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(output);
end;
Error report -
ORA-00904: "VAR1": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 9
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Elapsed: 00:00:00.082
```

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @Alfabravo: It did what I expected....is there a alternate way to do this...

Comment: `Var1` is a local to this pl/sql block variable. Dynamic SQL will not see it. For it it's an identifier it knows nothing about. In static SQL all pl/sql variables turned into bind variable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What if you use a substitution variable (`&`) as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513425/oracle-sql-statement-dynamic-schema-variable)?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov. Basically the idea that I am trying to implement here is to just add var3, var4 if I wanted to multiply 4 numbers. Add var5 if I wanted to multiply 5 numbers. I am trying to generate the variable name at runtime and then evaluate the variable to get the value.

Comment: @Alfabravo That does not help me because in my final solution I will be processing a record which is based on a table. So what I am trying to do is similar to this.

`declare

type t_emp_record_type is table of emp%rowtype;
v_emp_record t_t_emp_record_type;

for column_name in (select column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = __EMP__ order by column_id)
loop
     --Process each column from table and associated record member.
end loop;

END;`

Comment: Define collection then.  [Something like this](http://rextester.com/GLGFOY61574)

Comment: Pardon my editing. This is the first time I am posting here.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I will be working with a record here which will be getting the data at runtime.

Comment: Edit your question and include all relevant information instead of giving it piece by piece in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
declare
  var1    number := 1;
  var2    number := 2;
  output  number := 1;
  varname varchar2(10);
begin

  for counter in 1..2 loop
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := var'||counter ||'; END;' USING OUT output;
       dbms_output.put_line(output);
  end loop;

end;
```

Comment: No, it cannot be done like this.`var1` and `var2` are local to the dynamic anonymous PL/SQL block variables, which weren't declare there, thus you'll get the corresponding error message.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
DECLARE
   var1      NUMBER := 1;
   var2      NUMBER := 2;
   output    NUMBER := 1;
   varname   VARCHAR2 (10);
BEGIN
   FOR counter IN 1 .. 2 LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ''var''||:val1*:counter from dual'
         INTO varname
         USING var1, counter;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (varname);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Result:

```
var1 
var2
```